# Is there a word for spending a large amount of time solving a problem and then finding a simple answer?

Tags: debugging

Spending a large amount of time debugging only to realize a trivial issue like misplaced white-space, a missing comma, or a forgotten copy-paste adjustment. Many software engineers I've talked to confirm that this is a universal experience. Is there a word to describe this feeling of tragic incompetence?

Answer (score -1):

**Trivompetence** - The feeling of incompetence felt after struggling to solve a problem only to realize the solution was trivial.

Etymology: Trivial + Incompetence